# p:nth-child(n) not working within css divs

Tags: css-selectors

I am trying to control the padding of the first, second and third p tags within a div but can't seem to get it working, below is the code I have

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="icon-box-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s" data-wow-offset="150">
      <div class="icon-boxwrap2"><i class="fa fa-medkit icon-box-back2"></i></div>
      <div class="icon-box2-title">Free assessments</div>
      <p>
         We offer FREE 10 minute assessments at our clinics, to see if osteopathy is right for you.
      </p>
      <div class="iconbox-readmore"><a href="faqs.php">FAQs</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="icon-box-3 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.9s" data-wow-offset="150">
      <div class="icon-boxwrap2"><i data-icon="\e609" class="icon-stethoscope icon-box-back2"></i></div>
      <div class="icon-box2-title">Registered</div>
      <p>
         We are registered osteopaths with the General Osteopathic Council.
      </p>
      <div class="iconbox-readmore"><a href="about-ben.php">About</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="icon-box-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.2s" data-wow-offset="150">
      <div class="icon-boxwrap2"><i class="icon-ambulance icon-box-back2"></i></div>
      <div class="icon-box2-title">Areas Covered</div>
      <p>
         The areas generally covered are North London and Hertfordshire, but please do ring to see if we will cover your area.
      </p>
      <div class="iconbox-readmore"><a href="faqs.php">FAQs</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
<style>
   .icon-box-3 p:nth-child(1) {
   padding: 0 15px 37px 15px;
   }
   .icon-box-3 p:nth-child(2) {
   padding: 0 15px 37px 15px;
   }
   .icon-box-3 p:nth-child(3) {
   padding: 0 15px 37px 15px;
   }
</style>
```

When I do the above, it makes the all three p tags use the same css selector and uses the following line for some reason

```
         .icon-box-3 p:nth-child(3) {
           padding: 0 15px 37px 15px;
           }
```

I don't get where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply [nth-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) and [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) classes on parent selector. `icon-box-3` is a child under a parent div, which is why your class selection is failing.

```css
.icon-wrapper:nth-of-type(1) p {
  background: red;
  padding: 0 15px 37px 15px;
}
.icon-wrapper:nth-of-type(2) p {
  background: green;
  padding: 0 15px 37px 15px;
}
.icon-wrapper:nth-of-type(3) p {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 15px 37px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 icon-wrapper">
  <div class="icon-box-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s" data-wow-offset="150">
    <div class="icon-boxwrap2"><i class="fa fa-medkit icon-box-back2"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-box2-title">Free assessments</div>
    <p>
      We offer FREE 10 minute assessments at our clinics, to see if osteopathy is right for you.
    </p>
    <div class="iconbox-readmore"><a href="faqs.php">FAQs</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 icon-wrapper">
  <div class="icon-box-3 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.9s" data-wow-offset="150">
    <div class="icon-boxwrap2"><i data-icon="\e609" class="icon-stethoscope icon-box-back2"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-box2-title">Registered</div>
    <p>
      We are registered osteopaths with the General Osteopathic Council.
    </p>
    <div class="iconbox-readmore"><a href="about-ben.php">About</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 icon-wrapper">
  <div class="icon-box-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.2s" data-wow-offset="150">
    <div class="icon-boxwrap2"><i class="icon-ambulance icon-box-back2"></i></div>
    <div class="icon-box2-title">Areas Covered</div>
    <p>
      The areas generally covered are North London and Hertfordshire, but please do ring to see if we will cover your area.
    </p>
    <div class="iconbox-readmore"><a href="faqs.php">FAQs</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you this works for you, please accept the answer :)